# Is there any way to storing a text with some mathematical formula in database(mysql)?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to create a website about learning mathematics and I want to save page contents of the website which involves texts and formulas in database(mysql). How can I storing those (texts + mathematical formulas)?

Comment: If the user can key the formula in, then its just text. Text is easily saved to a database

Comment: For how to ask On Topic question, please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomend you look at something like [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) or [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)- this allows you to express complex mathematical formulae with a standard keyboard - this then also means that you can store them in MySQL as regular strings using field types such as `text` or `varchar`.

From there all you need is a library such as [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to render the formulae all nice and pretty again on output. Have a look at their [documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html), it contains some examples of what I'm suggesting :-)

Comment: I'm familiar with latex but I dont know how to do that in mysql.

Comment: Same way as you would store regular text (because that is all it is now thanks to latex), so just a standard `INSERT`.

Comment: Great, in that case please mark my answer as correct :-)

Comment: Hi @SAM if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.